# How do I get a cursor on every line in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiple-cursor

I'm trying to use the multi-cursor functionality of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on a large(ish) file. 
The file is too large to select every line individually with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd>. 
In [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), I would select everything and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>. 
Is there a similar thing in VS Code?
I've tried using a regex search for ^ (caret), but that gives me an error stating "Expression matches everything".

Answer (score 384, accepted):

The command Selection / Add Cursors to Line Ends <kbd>`alt`</kbd><kbd>`shift`</kbd><kbd>`i`</kbd> will put a cursor on every line in the current selection. (For mac use <kbd>`opt`</kbd><kbd>`shift`</kbd><kbd>`i`</kbd>)

Tip: You can pull up the keyboard shortcut reference sheet with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> (as in, those two keyboard combos in sequence).
(For mac use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>)

Comment: When I tried it, the cursor went to the end of each line.  I was looking for beginning of each line.  I saw an extension that will allow a keybinding for "cursor at beginning of line," but I was wondering if it's possible to do it in vanilla VS Code?

Comment: @Tiffany hit the `home` key after.

Comment: That should have been obvious for me.  But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Just for reference, to draw your cursors without first making a selection use alt + shift + drag selection. Those familiar with Sublime Text know this by using alt + drag selection.

Comment: `home` for Mac is `fn` + `left`

Comment: to add on to what @eibersji said. 

For Mac Users - 

To get to start of multi selected line.  

```shift + option + i ``` then press ```fn + left arrow ``` twice , and staying on same selection if you want to go to end of each line from  start type  ```fn + right arrow ```  twice

Comment: for Mac users:
before  `opt` `shift` `I` you must select your text ,for example `cmd` and `a` for affect all.

Comment: for Windows too. You need to "select all" first, with `Crtl + A`

Comment: Notice that VS Code limits to 9999 cursors at most

Answer (score 57):

- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Home</kbd> (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> Mac) for right-most or <kbd>End</kbd> for left most(<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd> Mac)

[image]

Comment: This answer saves me a lot of time. BTW, how do you record this gif?

Comment: On mac I was using `gifox` for such gifs.

Comment: Saved a ton of time.

Comment: As the animated GIF above shows, if your lines have tabs or spaces at the front, then pressing the Home key will put the cursor *after* the tab.  If you need your cursor to go absolutely to the front of the line, *before* the tab, then hit the Right Arrow key instead of the Home key.  Note: when making your text selection, you'll need to include the line before your first line, otherwise your first line gets skipped out this way.

Answer (score 46):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the block. Then press <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> button. 
You get selected individual lines.

I use version VSCode 1.5.3 in Windows.

Comment: This is a nice work around, but one of the few things I miss from sublime text, the old `ctrl + shift + L` to add cursors to all selected lines

Comment: @DesHorsley I think you're looking for `alt+shift+I`.

Comment: @ZachB you legend. Thanks!

Comment: @ZachB. Please make than an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: If you've changed your multi cursor key to `ctrlcmd` instead of `alt` then the shortcut for this is `ctrl + shift + drag` or `cmd + shift + drag`.

Comment: `ALT+SHIFT+I` is the answer for vscode users. However there is multiple cursor limitation that impedes you to edit +10000 lines. Currently being requested as a feat improvement here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81589

Answer (score 11):

This feature is actually called `split selection into lines` in many editors.

- Sublime Text uses the default keybinding, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>
- VSCode uses <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
- For Atom you actually need to edit your keymap to something like this

```
'.platform-win32 .editor, .platform-linux .editor':
  'ctrl-shift-L': 'editor:split-selections-into-lines'
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 9):

#### Real Lines vs Display Lines

First we have to understand the difference between **Real Lines** and **Display Lines** to completely understand the answer of the question.

When **Word Wrap** is enabled, each line of text that exceeds the width of the window will display as wrapped. As a result, a single line in the file may be represented by multiple lines on the display.

The easiest way to tell the difference between Real Lines and Display Lines is by looking at the line number in the left margin of the text editor. Lines that begin with a number correspond to the real lines, which may span one or more display lines. Each time a line is wrapped to fit inside the window, it **begins without a line number**.

###### Cursor At the Beginning of each Display Lines:

[image: display lines]

###### Cursor At the Beginning of each Real Lines:

[image]

#### Answer to the Question

Now that we know the difference between Display Lines and Real Lines, we can now properly answer the actual question.

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the text block.

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to put cursor on the beginning of every Display Line.

Press <kbd>End</kbd> to put cursor on the end of every Display Line.

Press <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> (<kbd>Home</kbd> twice) to put cursor on the beginning of every Real Line.

Press <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> (<kbd>End</kbd> twice) to put cursor on the end of every Real Line.

Please understand that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> put cursor at the end of every Real Line.

**Special Case:**

If there are **tabs at the beginning of each line**, then to put cursor at the beginning of every Real Line we have to use: <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>End</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>

If there are **empty lines between Lines** then before using the commands, we can use: `Remove empty lines: in Selection` which comes with the [Remove empty lines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.remove-empty-lines) extension.

The solution mentioned here for this particular scenario is somewhat tricky and non-deterministic. So, i use [select-by extension](https://github.com/rioj7/select-by?tab=readme-ov-file#move-by-calculation) to address the issue. The keybindings i use are:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+left",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections",
    "args": {
        "charNrEx": "0"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections",
    "args": {
        "charNrEx": "currentLine.length"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

> #### *How do I get a cursor on every line in VS Code?*

#### A. For small snippets

When the snippet is small, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>  or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> , as suggested in your question. 
If you accidentally mark one or two lines too many – press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> to *un*mark the last line. 
(Release <kbd>Alt</kbd> before pressing <kbd>U</kbd>.)

#### B. For large snippets

1. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Page up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Page down</kbd> – and <kbd>Shift</kbd>  or <kbd>Shift</kbd>  – to select the snippet.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>, then <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>. (Yes, that's <kbd>Home</kbd> *twice*.)
3. Type whatever it is you want your lines to start with.
   (For example, `>` .)

### Reference

- [The difference between actual/real lines and *displayed* lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263379)

Answer (score 1):

## Install the extension [Sublime Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zarel.sublime-commands).

> [Sublime Commands] Adds commands from Sublime Text to VS Code: Transpose, Expand Selection to Line, **Split into Lines**, Join Lines.

(Don't forget to add the keybinding(s) from the extensions details page to your `keybindings.json`)

---

#### Doesn't VS Code already have a "split into lines" command?

**Yes**, yes it does. However it differs from the one in Sublime.

In VS Code, when you split into lines your selection gets deselected and a cursor appears at the end of each line that was selected (except for the last line where the cursor appears at the end of the selection).

In Sublime, when you split into lines a cursor appears at the end of each line (with the same exception as in VS Code) **and** the selection is divided on each line and "given" to the same line.

Comment: Note that the OP is asking how to perform the task on vscode as they already know how it's done in sublime

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i'm used to Alt + drag to do 'box selections' in visual studio but it does'n work in code.

It seems to be impossible for now to do it differently than by selecting every single line.

However plugins should be supported soon so we will likely see a plugin for this if not implemented directly by microsoft.

[From visual studio uservoice forums:](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752408-plugin-system)

> We plan to offer plugin support for Visual Studio Code. Thank you for your interests and look for more details in our blog in the coming weeks. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode.
>
> For the preview we are looking for exactly this type of feedback. Keep it coming.
>
> Sean McBreen – VS Code Team Member