# Insert same text multiple lines using VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

I'm trying to insert the same word on multiple lines.  Much like how PowerShells ISE allows Alt-Shift so you can insert the same thing like a comma on multiple lines.
I can't seem to find the equivalent or right wording for the equivalent.

Comment: Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490989/how-do-i-get-a-cursor-on-every-line-in-vscode?rq=1 highlight area and alt+shift+i