# VScode shortcut is not working for add cursors to line ends

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to use the shortcut to add cursors to line ends, but it's not working.It does nothing

Comment: What hotkey are you pressing? Can you confirm in keyboard shortcuts menu that it's the correct one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a cursor on every line in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490989/how-do-i-get-a-cursor-on-every-line-in-vscode)

Comment: Dou you have any lines selected?  That is how it works.

Comment: ohh okay thank you